# how to run existing react project on vscode?

Tags: reactjs, npm-install, npm-start

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afiY0.png)
I have run existing project, but the browser keeps showing me this. I can't see the project. Just the icon of react is spinning.

I tried to npm install and npm run start. But on the browser showed up the icon of react. What should I do to see the project?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have another project running on the same default port.

Create a file with name .env in the main directory besides `package.json` and set PORT variable to desired port number.

For example:

.env

```
PORT=4200
```

then try it run again.

Comment: nothing changed bro :(